# HTML form enable one list of options or another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to display a form where a user can select a specific item from a list or a specific category of items from another list. I want them to select one or the other, not both.

I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247748/mvc3-validation-require-one-from-group) which solves how to handle this in the backend.

I still need to figure out how to properly show this in the view. 
I have the following sample which does what I would like to achieve, but I'm wondering if this is the way to go:

```js
$('.formGroup input:checkbox').on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).prop('id');
  var groups = $(this).parents('.formGroup').siblings('.formGroup');
  var thisGroup = $(this).parents('.formGroup');

  $('select', thisGroup).prop('disabled', false);

  $.each(groups, function(index, item) {
    var checkbox = $('input:checkbox', item);
    var select = $('select', item);

    checkbox.prop('checked', false);
    select.val(-1).prop('disabled', true);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formGroup">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" id="Option1">Select an Item</label>
  <select disabled="disabled">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="formGroup">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" id="Option2">Or select a Category</label>
  <select disabled="disabled">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Category 1</option>
    <option value="2">Category 2</option>
    <option value="3">Category 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Possible problem of the current solution

If you check one of the checkboxes, it gets activated and the `select`-element becomes enabled. If you click the same checkbox again, you only uncheck it, but the `select`-element stays enabled. I'd say there are two possibilities here:

- disable the `select`-element as well
- don't let the user uncheck the `input`-element

<s>In the following examples I went with the first option.</s>
As requested in the comments, I've updated the review to work for the second option.

#### Reduce the number of DOM queries and cache selectors

You didn't say how many of those groups are present or how often a user is going to make this decision. But you do a lot of the same DOM queries in your event handler over and over again.

At first let's store the "group-selector" in a string, to make it re-usebale. Then select all groups:

```
const selector = '[data-form-group]';
const groups = $(selector);
```

You can stick to classes if you like. I tend to use `data-*`-attributes to couple JavaScript.

---

As we also often need the `input`- and the `select`-element in each group, let's store them as well:

```
groups.each(function() {
    const group = $(this);
    group.data('checkbox', group.find('input'));
    group.data('select', group.find('select'));
});
```

Now we can access the form elements anytime, without re-querying the DOM.

#### The actual event handler

Attach the event handler to each `input`-element, the <s>checkboxes</s> radio-buttons. Then test, whether the current group is "enabled", i.e. the `input`-element is `checked`:

*If it is `checked` already*

- do nothing and simply return

*If it is not `checked`*

- enable the `select`-element
- run through all other groups and disable them

The final code could look like this:

```
const selector = '[data-form-group]';
const groups = $(selector);

groups.each(function() {
  const group = $(this);
  group.data('toggle', group.find('input'));
  group.data('options', group.find('select'));

  group.data('toggle').on('change', function() {
    const selectedGroup = $(this).closest(selector);

    if (!selectedGroup.data('toggle').is(':checked')) {
      return;
    }

    selectedGroup.data('options').prop('disabled', false);

    groups.each(function() {
      const current = $(this);

      if (selectedGroup[0] === current[0]) {
        return;
      }

      current.data('toggle').prop('checked', false);
      current.data('options').prop('disabled', true);
    });
  });
});
```

[Try it yourself](https://jsfiddle.net/sozd0x44/)

Comment: I like it. Thanks. One thing i am not sure about is if i would like it more to not have the ability to de-select, so it behaves like a radio button. One of the selection is mandatory so no reason to de-select. I am also considering having a pre-selected option on load. And last thing is that i would remove the selection when another checkbox is selected, as this data is going to be posted and i would not like to send irrelevant data.

Comment: I have this https://jsfiddle.net/jyparask/9pd45rbx/1/ based on your answer. Make note that the last line is only for a show case. In real life scenario i will handle this effect from the back end since it will depend on if it is a new entry so select the first option or an edit so select whichever option the user had selected.

Comment: I've updated the review and also the example at the end of it, to work with `radio`-buttons and with a pre-selected group. If you don't want to send disabled groups, remove them before sending the form – *on submit*. I hope this is helpful, @GiannisParaskevopoulos.

Comment: I think the radio buttons seem more natural. Do not get me wrong, i will accept your answer as it really does what i wanted. I do have three comments though. 1. I would rename checkbox in `group.data('checkbox'` to `radio` just to make it more obvious (i really got confused at first). 2. I think the part for checking if the radio is checked and return is unnecessary, as radio buttons work this way. 3. I would stick to clearing the selected option when changing the option in order to make clear to the user it won't send this value as well. https://jsfiddle.net/jyparask/q6ycfce2/1/

Comment: And a bit of question if i may. I see you declare `const group` and then inside the on click event you declare `const group = $(this).closest(selector);`. Now, i know the scope is different, but still, for readability's shake, wouldn't it be better if you had named it differently? I myself (no, i do not boast to be a super-duper developer) had to read it twice.

Comment: Another question if i may. Is there any real gain in using `const` over `var` in this sample? In any way, thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: **Naming**: You're right about the names of `group` and `checkbox`. I didn't have time to update them this morning, but included an updated version now. **Exit early**: The return is used to improve performance. If you know, that nothing is to do, it's not necessary to execute the rest of the function and enable the current list of options and to loop through all groups again. @GiannisParaskevopoulos

Comment: Here are some questions about `var|let|const`. Maybe something of this is helpful for you: [How much should I be using 'let' vs 'const' in ES6?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6) or [es6 iterate object with var, let, or const?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44275117/1456376) @GiannisParaskevopoulos.

Comment: Thanks again for everything. You have been much of a help. I will insist though about the early exit. The even is 'change' and apparently is not being triggered if there is no change. Clicking on a selected radio button won't change it. To make my point of course i added an alert right on top of the change function :) https://jsfiddle.net/jyparask/sozd0x44/2/